# change window.navigator JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, browser

I'm trying to change window.navigator. But for some reason can't change it:

```
--
[10:40:28.802] window.navigator['buildID'];
[10:40:28.811] "20121129162756"
--
[10:40:47.225] window.navigator['appCodeName'] = "I want to change it";
[10:40:47.234] "I want to change it"
--
[10:40:55.633] window.navigator['appCodeName'];
[10:40:55.643] "Mozilla"
--
[10:41:02.405] window.navigator['myProperty'] = 'someproperty';
[10:41:02.414] "someproperty"
--
[10:41:07.651] window.navigator['myProperty'];
[10:41:07.660] "someproperty"
```

Hope my question is clear: 'How to change window.navigator?'

Comment: Are you trying to punish browser sniffing?

Comment: Already have an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808968/change-navigator-platform-on-chrome-firefox-or-ie-to-test-os-detection-code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change navigator.platform on Chrome, Firefox, or IE to test OS detection code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808968/change-navigator-platform-on-chrome-firefox-or-ie-to-test-os-detection-code)

Answer (score 5):

You can't. Its pre-existing properties are read-only. Why you would want to modify it is beyond me...

Comment: No, but why would you want to?

Comment: I use JavaScript with python, and need to have my own version of browser.

Comment: That makes no sense... But anyway, it's read-only and that's that.